# Hibernate как правильно связать таблицы

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, j2ee

У меня есть таблица `messages`, в ней есть ссылка на отправителя и получателя из таблицы `users`. Как правильно их связать в hibernate mapping (xml) а то совсем запутался. По идее, получатель — это связь к `user_id` типа один-ко-многим, а отправитель многие-ко-многим? Также в связи многие-ко-многим IDE подчеркивает строки красным, а многие-к-одному — наоборот.

Вот *messages xml* — http://pastebin.com/8cF3VPpD , *users xml* — http://pastebin.com/1HjfvELE.

Снимки экрана:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот связь между таблицами: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Есть специальные инструменты, которым можно указать параметры подключения к БД, а они сами создадут сущностные классы со всеми аннотациями (или mapping-овые xml-ки) на основе таблиц из БД, их структуры и связей.

Вот ссылка на вопрос, где это обсуждается: [IntelliJ IDEA 10 generate entity (POJO) from DB model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259276/intellij-idea-10-generate-entity-pojo-from-db-model).

И еще хорошая ссылка по этой теме: [How to generate Hibernate mapping files & annotation with Hibernate Tools](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/).